# Maven Build Fails when "spring-boot-starter-web-services" starter is used with 2.1.13.RELEASE of Spring Boot Version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-services

I am not able to build spring boot application when spring web service starter is used with 2.1.13.RELEASE version of spring boot.  This is coming due to spring-ws-core:jar:3.0.8.RELEASE.

**Exception while building application :**  It comes during default test case execution .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/transform/TransformerObjectSupport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerObjectSupport
```

**Warning :**

The POM for org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:3.0.8.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

**Pom File :**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many ways to solve the issue, the best option is :-
Use a newer version of spring-boot-starter-parent
e.g.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

issue solved.